# xpages - datasource view name issue

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a difficulty understanding regarding `Data source name` for views.

Let say I'm using 5 XPages in my XPiNC application and each xpage contains a view. I noticed that after I drag the view from the container control, for each view I have `view1` as the `Data source name`. It is necessary to change it ( the data source name ) from the start?

Or just if the near future I will programmatic call this view by its Data Source Name?

Some clarifications are welcome.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Data source name` has only to be **unique within** an XPage or Custom Control. It is up to you to use the default name "view1" or to give it a more descriptive name.

You can include in an XPage several Custom Controls which all have the same data source name "view1" as the name is only used within the Custom Control itself.

Comment: So, if I have, let say, 4 views on 4 custom controls, and each CC is on a different xpage ( 4 xpages in total ), it means I MUST have 4 different Data source names?

Comment: @KnutHermann: Data sources have *NOT* to be unique within CC's / XPages, and are not used in the custom controls. The last one "wins".

Comment: @Sven: I meant with "unique within" that you can't define the same data source name e.g. "view1" within an XPages or CC itself twice. But, you can include in an XPage several CC which all have the same data source name inside.

Comment: @KnutHermann: But this is not correct. You can define data sources with the same name multiple times on the same XPage or CC.

Comment: @Sven: Ok, you're right. I tried to create a second "view1" in Custom Control's properties and got the error message "Attribute value must be unique". But, if I changed the name in source later to "view1" I can save CC without an error. Although, it doesn't make sense to use the same name twice *within* an Xpage or CC...

Comment: @KnutHermann: *it doesn't make sense* != *you cannot do that*